# .ical standard format for Outlook and Google Calendar?

Tags: icalendar

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
TZID:Eastern Time Zone
SUMMARY:Mount view
DTSTART:20150310T01:00:00Z
LOCATION:CHRIS NISWANDEE BITBOOST TUCSON Alabama 85728
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:Spring is one of the four conventional temperate seasons, following winter and preceding summer. There are various technical definitions of spring, but local usage of the term varies according to local climate, cultures and customs.
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
TZID:Eastern Time Zone
SUMMARY:Mount view
DTSTART:20150310T01:00:00Z
LOCATION:CHRIS NISWANDEE BITBOOST TUCSON Alabama 85728
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:Spring is one of the four conventional temperate seasons, following winter and preceding summer. There are various technical definitions of spring, but local usage of the term varies according to local climate, cultures and customs.
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
TZID:Eastern Time Zone
SUMMARY:Reiver view
DTSTART:20150311T13:25:59Z
LOCATION:100 MAIN ST PO BOX 1022 SEATTLE Hawaii 98104
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:Spring is one of the four conventional temperate seasons, following winter and preceding summer. There are various technical definitions of spring, but local usage of the term varies according to local climate, cultures and customs.
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
TZID:Eastern Time Zone
SUMMARY:Reiver view
DTSTART:20150312T11:30:26Z
LOCATION:The Honorable Charles W. Anderson (Dear Mr. Ambassador:) 2050 Bamako Place DC Washington 20521-2050
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:Spring is one of the four conventional temperate seasons, following winter and preceding summer. There are various technical definitions of spring, but local usage of the term varies according to local climate, cultures and customs.
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
TZID:Eastern Time Zone
SUMMARY:Site seeing
DTSTART:20150312T15:50:23Z
LOCATION:The Honorable Charles W. Anderson (Dear Mr. Ambassador:) 2050 Bamako Place DC Washington 20521-2050
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:Spring is one of the four conventional temperate seasons, following winter and preceding summer. There are various technical definitions of spring, but local usage of the term varies according to local climate, cultures and customs.
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
TZID:Eastern Time Zone
SUMMARY:Breakfast
DTSTART:20150315T23:55:13Z
LOCATION:1500 N Congress Ave #3E18  Austin Texas 78701
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:Spring is one of the four conventional temperate seasons, following winter and preceding summer. There are various technical definitions of spring, but local usage of the term varies according to local climate, cultures and customs.
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The above .ics file is workign fine on Outlook, but when I import to Google Calendar, the event start time shows an incorrect value.

What is missing from the above .ics file?

Can anyone provide a standard .ics file format with a clear example?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to export an event from a Google calendar and see the difference.

Comment: Ok. thanks. Do you have any standard format for .ics file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DTSTART format should look like

DTSTART:20150310T010000Z

Then, for each event, you have a TZID property which is illegal within a VEVENT.

But are your DTSTART expressed in zulu (utc) time or in some local timezone ?